# Downloading a tile in OpenStreetMap, georeference it and export to .jpg or. tiff

Tags: geotiff-tiff, jpg

Quick explanation of what I need:

1. I need to get a good quality street map size 1 degree x 1 degree.
   Lets say S25 E 28 and S 26 E 29
   If possible zoom level 14 at least.
2. After downloading this tile, I need to convert it to a .jpg or .Tiff file.
   This tile will then be georeferenced to coordinates S25 E 28 and S 26 E 29 in another program what II have.
   (Problem this converted file, .jpg/.Tiff file must not exceed 20 Mb. In other words, the program I'm using can't process it).

What are the steps to download a tile and how can I convert it?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: please clarify "good quality" 150 dpi, 300 dpi,1200 dpi? - you might want to to get vector tiles rather than raster (72dpi) tiles.

Comment: Mapperz.. sorry canor realy answer your question please look at the link i attached, maybe that will make more sence for you ,  thanks for the  replying.
https://www.mglavionics.co.za/Software/MapMaker2.exe